# Replacing chandelier, I have 5 different colours of wires coming out of the ceiling

Tags: wiring

[image]

I took a chandelier off and didn't took pic of the wiring. I have 4 cables with red black and green and an extra 2 cables, one with yellow( with green stripe) and black. And one with red and white. When I connect only the red and black the light switch doesn't turn the light off and it stays on all the time. 
How should I contact it?

Comment: Where are you on this planet? This looks like Aussie or old UK colors...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're in Australia (or NZ), and assuming the original installation was done correctly

the black is is the neutral, the blacks go together and connect to the chandelier Neutral terminal. the red is active, all the reds go together and connect to nothing else, all the green and green-yellow are ground and go together and connect to the body of the chandelier (if it's metal, else nothing)
the white is the power feed, from the switch and connects to the other chandelier terminal power terminal.

If the chandelier has a "loop" terminal you can use that for the reds, if not get the modern version of the screw connector like the one on the green earth wires.
https://www.mitre10.com.au/hpm-connector

Comment: Thanks M8. Yes I am in Australia and found the same answer in Pinterent.